# Prevent multiple calls to the method using rxjava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-javafx

There are two events - `event1` and `event2` which can call `getA()`, these two events could occur simultaneously and trigger `getA`. I don't want to call `getA` multiple times until it gets done. I am using `isDisposed()` to check if its still active and calling `dispose()` explicitly in `doFinally` and setting fetchADisposable as null . Is there a better way to do this ?

Disposable fetchADisposable;

```
public void getA() {
    fetchA() //returns Observable
            .doFinally(new Action() {
        fetchADisposable.dispose();
        fetchADisposable = null;
            }).subscribe() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe (Disposable d){
            fetchADisposable = d;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext () {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError (Throwable e){
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete () {
        }
    }
}

public void event1() {
    if (fetchADisposable == null || fetchADisposable.isDisposed()) {
        getA();
    }
}

public void event2() {
    if (fetchADisposable == null || fetchADisposable.isDisposed()) {
        getA();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your existing solution has race conditions. You really need queuing to take place so that the events are processed serially.

The serialization of processing can be done using a `PublishSubject` that is subscribed to once only (say in the constructor or in an initializer method). The code looks like:

```
final PublishSubject<Integer> subject = createSubject();

private static PublishSubject<Integer> createSubject() {
    PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.<Integer>create().serialized();
    subject.subscribe(subscriber);
}

public void getA() {
    subject.onNext(1);
}
```